# correct way for catching aws boto3 errors

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

why to use botocore.exceptions.ClientError for catching instead of python inbuilt Exception, what is the recommended way and what are the advantages of using botocore exceptions
I have the following codes

```
except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as error:
        logger.info(error)
```

```
except Exception as error:
        logger.info(str(error))
```

For the above code snippets the output through logger is same when object doesn't exists or wrong key is given

`INFO:root:An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.`

Comment: They're the same for that error.  Not for all possible errors, for instance, if the connection fails, a EndpointConnectionError could be raised, and the first example won't catch the error, the second will.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `botocore.exceptions.ClientError` then you will get specifically identifies the error as an AWS client error and this error helps you to solve more errors that are related to AWS libraries in the future.

Also you can use simple python `Exception` error handling. But I think you need to use `botocore.exceptions.ClientError` handler for dealing specific error resolutions in the future.

Comment: My seniors are using Exception instead of botocore.exceptions.ClientError, I don't know why

Comment: But you can use `botocore.exceptions.ClientError`. This will help you more sure.